# Google Api + List members of a group with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-groups-api

Well, basicaly I'm lost with this task. I need to get all members of a group with the api google privedes. I'm starting with [gmail quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) example, first I have configure Api project and the OAuth client.

My first test was to see all the messages I have in my inbox, all ok. But to do the same with groups members I'm lost, I can't find the way to do it.

Any idea?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import json
import requests

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member'

def main():
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/example@test.com/members")
    print(response)
```

**The response is a:**

```
<Response [401]>
```

Comment: Where is this code run? Client machine, server, elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you started with the gmail example and then modified to access the admin/group function

Check the admin docs here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python

Comment: Thanks! this helped me solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

here is the function, it will retrieve all groups email addressess

```
def retrieving_groups():

response_group = service.groups().list(customer='my_customer').execute()
for group in response_group['groups']:
    print(group['email'])
```